# Disable hive support in sparklyr

Tags: r, sparklyr

Is there any way to disable the hive support in sparklyr?

Just like in SparkR:

```
sparkR.session(master="local[*]", enableHiveSupport=FALSE)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That option was introduced in sparklyr 1.3.0 after breaking [Ron's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54278307/10728093) solution on version 1.2.0 as described on [issue #2460](https://github.com/sparklyr/sparklyr/issues/2460).

```
library(sparklyr)

config <- spark_config()
config$sparklyr.connect.enablehivesupport <- FALSE

sc <- spark_connect(master = "local", config = config)
```

Answer (score 4):

You can disable Hive in sparklyr by setting the SQL catalog implementation to `in-memory`.

```r
# get the default config
conf <- spark_config()
# set the catalog implementation, defaults to hive, but we want it in-memory
conf$spark.sql.catalogImplementation <- "in-memory"
sc <- spark_connect(master = "local", config = conf)
```